# How to determine the Galois group of a general polynomial over rational number field?

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

How to determine the Galois group of a general polynomial over rational number field? For example $f(X)=X^n-X-3$, where $n$ is an positive number.${}$

Comment: This is a difficult problem in general and an active research area. The range of examples that can be presented in courses on Galois Theory is unfortunately very limited. At the moment, the available computer algorithms work fine for degrees up to about $31$ but usually fail for larger degrees. You should do a search for "algorithms to compute Galois groups" if you want to learn about it.

Comment: The Galois group of $x^n-x-3$ is the full symmetric group $S_n$ for $2 \le n \le 32$.